# Как я могу закодировать эту иконку меню только с помощью CSS и одним элементом?

Tags: html, css, css-animation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что до сих пор получилось:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:20px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.mobil-menu__icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 100%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 40%, #fff 40%, #fff 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 80%, #fff 80%, #fff 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="mobil-menu__icon"></div>
```

Comment: Ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56872934/7394871

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для имитации onclick добавил `:focus`  т.е работает при клике, как сделать transition не знаю

```css
.btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(red 0, red 10px, red 10px, #fff 10px, #fff 20px, red 20px, red 30px, #fff 30px, #fff 40px, red 40px, red 40px);
  transition: 0.34s;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
}

.btn:focus {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 0, transparent 10px, transparent 30px, red 30px, red 40px, transparent 40px, transparent 50px), linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 0, #fff 10px, #fff 30px, red 30px, red 40px, #fff 40px, #fff 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте только `solid`(сплошной) цвет в градиенте и используйте  `background-size:`

```css
.mobil-menu__icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background:
    /*                         position    / width height */
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top    left / 100%  20%,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) center left / 80%   20%,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom left / 60%   20%,
    red;
  border:10px solid red;
  background-repeat:no-repeat; /* Never forget this! */
}
```

```html
<div class="mobil-menu__icon"></div>
```

Пример c  анимацией наведения:

```css
.mobil-menu__icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) top    left,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) center left,
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) bottom left,
    red;
  background-size:
    100% 20%,
    80%  20%,
    60%  20%;
  border:10px solid red;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transition:0.3s all;
}
.mobil-menu__icon:hover {
  background-size:100% 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobil-menu__icon"></div>
```

И если вы хотите пример  с прозрачностью:

```css
.mobil-menu__icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red) 0    calc(1*100%/4) / 100%  20%,
    linear-gradient(red,red) 0    calc(3*100%/4) / 100%  20%,
    
    linear-gradient(red,red) 100% calc(2*100%/4) / 20%  20%,
    linear-gradient(red,red) 100% calc(4*100%/4) / 40%  20%;
  border:10px solid red;
  background-repeat:no-repeat; 
}

body {
  background:repeating-linear-gradient(to right,white 0 5px,grey 10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="mobil-menu__icon"></div>
```

У вас был почти хороший  код, но вам не хватало размера и повторения:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #000;
}

.mobil-menu__icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #fff 20%, transparent 20%, transparent 100%), 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 40%, #fff 40%, #fff 60%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%), 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 0%, transparent 80%, #fff 80%, #fff 100%);
   background-size:100% 100%,80% 100%, 60% 100%;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobil-menu__icon"></div>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56872998/7394871): @Temani Afif

Answer (score 2):

События надо не `hover`, а `onclick`. Сделал для примера:

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.btn:after,
.btn:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.34s;
}

.btn:after {
  top: 0;
}

.btn:before {
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn:hover span {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn:hover:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg)translateY(15px)translateX(5px);
}

.btn:hover:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg)translateY(-15px)translateX(7px);
}


/*******/

.prev {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.prev span {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.prev:after,
.prev:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.34s;
}

.prev:after {
  top: 0;
}

.prev:before {
  bottom: 0;
}

.prev:hover span {
  width: 70px;
  height: 8px;
}

.prev:hover:after {
  transform: translateX(35px)rotate(50deg);
  height: 8px;
}

.prev:hover:before {
  transform: translateX(35px)rotate(-50deg);
  height: 8px;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="btn">
  <span></span>
</a>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="" class="prev" title="Смотреть далее">
  <span></span>
</a>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  да я знаю, хотел чешуёй блеснуть :))

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  вечером тоже самое на градиенте сделаю если получится